# How to listing using loops in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I want to list the data from the API I am using. But I'm getting an error.

```
    // Here I'm getting the data.
    componentWillMount() {
    tokenner()
      .then(responseJson => {
        const token = "Bearer " + responseJson.result.token;
        this.setState({ token });
        fetch(
          "myapiurl//notimportant",
          {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              Accept: "application/json",
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              Authorization: token
            }
          }
        )
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(responseData => {
            this.setState({
              isLoading: false,
              dataSource: responseData.result
            });
          });
      })
      .catch(error => console.warn(error));
  }
```

Then I use the following codes to list this data I get:

```
render() {
if (this.state.isLoading) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ActivityIndicator />
    </View>
  );
} else {
  console.warn(this.state.dataSource) // I got the data. Everything ok.
  this.state.dataSource.map((val, key) => {
    return ( // There was no data returned error.
      <View key={key} style={styles.item}>
      <Text>{val.id}</Text>
      <Text>{val.name}</Text>
      <Text>{val.surname}</Text>
      <Text>{"Sıra" + key}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  });
}
```

}
}

the error:
[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmN0G.png)

The program does not generate an error when I print a result without using a loop.
What should I do?

Comment: Your else branch doesn't have a return statement. Render function should always return. Try adding return in the else branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```
this.state.dataSource.map((val, key) => {
    return (
      <View key={key} style={styles.item}>
        <Text>{val.id}</Text>
        <Text>{val.name}</Text>
        <Text>{val.surname}</Text>
        <Text>{"Sıra" + key}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  });
```

^ this is actually an array of elements. you have to return this inside render

```
render(){
 ......
 return this.state.dataSource.map((val, key) => {
    return (
      <View key={key} style={styles.item}>
        <Text>{val.id}</Text>
        <Text>{val.name}</Text>
        <Text>{val.surname}</Text>
        <Text>{"Sıra" + key}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You aren't returning the output of your map, i.e.

```
return this.state.dataSource.map((val, key) => {
  return (
    <View key={key} style={styles.item}>
      <Text>{val.id}</Text>
      <Text>{val.name}</Text>
      <Text>{val.surname}</Text>
      <Text>{"Sıra" + key}</Text>
    </View>
  );
});
```

The inner return statement, is for the function that is running on each item in `dataSource`, but you then need to `return` the array that this built

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? You forgot returning in the else statement

```
...
 return this.state.dataSource.map((val, key)
....
```